# Self updating docker stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, auto-update

I have a docker stack deployed with 20+ services which comprise my application. I would like to know that is there a way to update this stack with the latest changes to the software from within one of the containers running as a part of the stack?

Approach i have tried:

1. In one of the containers for a service, mounted the docker socket and the /usr/bin/docker file and downloaded the latest compose file from the server.
2. Instantiated a script which downloads the latest images
3. Initiate a `docker stack deploy` with the new compose file

Everything works fine this way but if the service which is running this process itself has an update and if that `docker stack deploy` tries to create this service before any other service in the stack, then the stack update fails.
Any suggestion or alternative approaches for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box solution for docker swarm mode (something like watchtower for single docker).  I think you already found the best solution for doing this automatically.  I would suggest you put the update container (the one that is updating the services) on a ignore list.  Then on one of your master nodes, create a cron that updates that one container.  I know this is not a prefect solution, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is to build a new Docker image that contains your new application code.  Tag it (as in the `docker build -t` argument) with some unique version, like a source control tag or date stamp.  Start a new container with the new application code, then stop and delete the old container.

As a general rule you do *not* upgrade the software inside a running container.  Delete the old container and start a new container with the software and version you want.  Also, this is generally managed by an operator, a continuous deployment system, or an orchestration system, not by the container itself.  (Mounting the Docker socket into a container is a significant security exposure.)

(Imagine setting up a second copy of your cluster that works exactly the same way as your production cluster, except that it has the software you want to deploy tomorrow.  You don't want your production cluster picking that up on its own until you've tested it.  This scheme should give you a reproducible deployment setup so that it's easy to start that pre-production cluster, but also give you control over which specific versions are running where.)